# There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "robot2" game object, but a script is trying to access it

Tags: unity-game-engine

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the
>   "robot2" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You
>   probably need to add a Renderer to the game object "robot2". Or your
>   script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
>   UnityEngine.Renderer.get_material () (at
>   <94c5f4c38cdc42d2b006f8badef04394>:0) ColorChange.Start () (at
>   Assets/ColorChange.cs:21)

I have a fbx robot2 in my Unity program, it have been imported as a Asset. I want change the color when program start, but I get this message. How could I render my fbx in Unity?

[image]

```
public Color colorStart = Color.red;
public Color colorEnd = Color.green;
public Renderer rend;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rend.material.color = colorStart;
}
```

Comment: Robot2 has no renderer component attached. It looks like there are child gameobjects that likely have renderers. Child gameobjects are not included in the GetComponent<Renderer>(); lookup.

Comment: And how could render and change colors of childs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the error message says it all:

[`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html) only returns a component attached to the **same** `GameObject` as your script.

But your `robo2` has no mesh and therefore also no `Renderer`.

---

What you rather want to do in your case would be using [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html) which rather returns all according components attached to the `GameObject` itself your script is attached to or any child object nested under it recursively

```
void Start()
{
    // pass true in order to also include disabled or inactive child Renderer
    foreach(var rend in GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true))
    {
        rend.material.color = colorStart;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is car?

Comment: @Liliymas a typo ^^ I wrote this on my smartphone so sorry for that ;) I noted another one my auto-correct removed the `s` .. it should be `GetComponentsInChildren` in order to get all not only the first one

Comment: Thanks mate! exactly what i needed. Now I don't get any error and all the necessary objects appear in the scene !

Comment: @Liliymas car or automobile is a motor vehicle with wheels. you can find more info in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car

Answer (score -1):

```
void Start()
{
    foreach(var rend in GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true))
    {
        rend.material.SetColor("_Color", colorStart);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.